# Call a powershell script with variables declared which are to used by multiple powershell scripts

Tags: vb.net

I have 10 scripts which are using common variables and functions .
I wanted to have two common scripts one with variables and other with all common functions.

How to call these scripts in my main script?

Pls. help!

I am too new to this  :(

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your .ps1 script that contains variables and functions then in your other scripts you have to call that file with a "."

EX:

Script with functions:

```
# function.ps1
function test($text)
{
    write-host $text
}
```

Script you want to run:

```
# Script.ps1
."Z:\function.ps1"
Test "this is a test"
```